# Use of couple and meaning

Tags: meaning

Couple - Can I say I have a couple of kids meaning that I have a girl and a boy, or it is only for number, not gender?

Comment: Not as obvious as it might appear. After all, a married couple was for most of our history a male and a female. But here, a couple of = a brace of = a pair of = 2.

Comment: _A couple_ as a noun phrase without qualification refers to a matched pair of some kind, which includes the matched pairing of marriage. But as part of the quantifier _(a) couple of_ /(a)'kəplə/, it has no reference to gender or wedlock, but only to paucal number (not necessarily just dual).

Comment: _Couple_ often means "two" but can also mean "an indefinite small number." So, one could say, "I went to the park and saw a couple kids there" even if I saw a trio of children.

Comment: @J.R. I'm pretty sure couple only means two. "I saw a few kids at the park" would make sense though.

Comment: If you refer to a pair of siblings a a couple and expect it to be understood that they're a male-female pair, you should also expect some rather unpleasant understandings about the nature of their relationship to arise.

Comment: @toryan - _couple_ doesn't "only" mean two. [Collins #2](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-couple-of#a-couple-of_1): "(informal) a small number of; a few". [Webster's #4](http://www.yourdictionary.com/couple): "an indefinite small number; a few". [Macmillan #1a](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/couple): "a small number of things or people" – although that last reference is labeled `MAINLY AMERICAN`, so perhaps that explains why _couple_ used in that sense seems off to you. (Good to know I should stick with _few_ in the U.K., though.) :^)

Comment: @J.R. thinking about it again, it does make a kind of sense but maybe it is a regional thing. In the sentence "he'll be off sick for a couple of days" I can understand couple to mean 2, 3 or 4 days because you might not know for definite how long he will be away, but if you said "I saw a couple of children playing on the swings" then I would assume that you knew how many children there were and that there were two. Maybe that's just me though...

Comment: @toryan - I think we agree. If I was meeting a relative, and I knew who the kids were (my nephews Jason and Keith, e.g.), chances are pretty good that _a couple of_ would mean _two_: _I met a couple of my nephews at the park yesterday_. However, if I wasn't really paying attention to the number, but was just vaguely aware that some kids were playing on the swings, then _a couple_ could mean _two or a few more_: _I thought the park was still closed, but I saw a couple kids playing on the swings there_.

Answer (score 3):

See, you can't say:

> We're a couple of people.

to express that you and your husband are ***a couple*** (***a*** man and ***a*** woman). The way you say it would be:

> We're a couple.

The same rule counts for *a couple of kids* in your question. That **doesn't** mean that there are a boy and a girl. That also isn't saying that there are *literally* two kids. *A couple of* something means *there are 2, 3, 4, ...* of that something.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted? It's the most detailed and relevant answer, and not inaccurate, so far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh, was it? I didn't know. Thanks, I've voted up your comment. (y)

Answer (score 1):

only for numbers.  Couples can be same-sex too.

Answer (score 0):

You can say you have a couple of kids if you have two children, but that doesn't imply a biy and a girl, just that there are two of them.